# How to find href=blah but not href=/blah with Full-text search

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I'm currently using the query

```
SELECT Url FROM Link WHERE CONTAINS(Url, 'href=blah')
```

It is including results with `href=/blah`. Any way I can tell the query to act more like `WHERE Url LIKE '%href=blah%'` and still use the full-text catalog?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `=` and `/` are both word breakers, in other words, sql fulltext is actually searching for `href` and `blah`

There are a couple of options you could try. First you could filter down the search domain using the fulltext engine, then search the subset of data using `LIKE`. You'll need to experiment to see how to squeeze out the best performance.

The other option is, if `href=blah` is a consistent term you could add that to a custom dictionary. A good article on this is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2009/12/03/did-you-know-that-sql-server-2008-provides-the-ability-to-create-a-custom-dictionary-of-special-terms-to-be-indexed-as-is-i-e-at-t-into-the-ftindex.aspx).